# JavaScript - Create flashcards to PDF

Tags: javascript, html, json, pdf

I have a JSON object that I need to convert to a downloadable PDF file in the format of flashcards. Here is an example of the JSON:

```
{
    questions : [
        {"front": "ABC", "back" : "DEF"},
        {"front": "HIJ", "back" : "KLM"},
        {"front": "NOP", "back" : "QRS"}
    ]
}
```

The flashcards should be in a table of 2 columns and 3 rows. ABC etc. on the left and DEF etc. on the right

How would I generate a PDF from the JSON object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could open a new window, and print it to PDF:
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/97btphn4/)

(Be sure to allow pop-ups, otherwise it won't work.)

---

```
let questions = [
          {"front": "ABC", "back" : "DEF"},
          {"front": "HIJ", "back" : "KLM"},
          {"front": "NOP", "back" : "QRS"}
      ];
function printCards() {
  let container = document.createElement("div");
  questions.forEach(question => {
    let card = document.createElement("div");
    card.classList.add("card");
    let front = document.createElement("div");
    front.classList.add("front");
    front.textContent = question.front;
    card.appendChild(front);
    let back = document.createElement("div");
    back.classList.add("back");
    back.textContent = question.back;
    card.appendChild(back);
    container.appendChild(card);
  });
  let style = document.getElementById('style');
  let printWindow = window.open("", "print", "");
  printWindow.document.open();
  printWindow.document.write(container.outerHTML + style.outerHTML);
  printWindow.document.close();
  printWindow.print();
}
```

---

```
<style id="style">
  div.card {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 12cm;
  }
  div.card > div {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 4cm;
    width: 6cm;
  }
  div.front {
    background-color: green;
  }
  div.back {
    background-color: red;
  }
</style>
<button onclick="printCards();">Print</button>
```

---

By default, most browsers will remove background colors when printing. You can keep the background graphics by changing the settings:

**Chrome**
[image: Chrome]
**Firefox**
[image: Firefox]

Comment: When I click on the button in your code, I am taken to the page with the cards to print but the colour is lost and some of the borders disappear. Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: @marmadukeandbob I edited my answer.

Comment: If the program was run by anyone, would they all have to do that? Is there a way to enable that as default?

Comment: Also, some of the borders are still hidden

Comment: [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-print-color-adjust](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-print-color-adjust)

Comment: And what about the borders?

Comment: Can't reproduce.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172437/discussion-between-marmadukeandbob-and-tttapa).

Comment: Those are just artifacts from the print preview on a low-resolution screen. When you export it, it looks fine.